# Xamarin Android - Error inflating class fragment - Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, fragment, inflate-exception

I've seen others with a similar issue, but none of their solutions seemed to work for me. The Exception being thrown is:

`Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment`

map.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_map_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout...>
            <CheckBox... />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout...>
          <CheckBox... />
        </LinearLayout>
        <EditText.../>
    </LinearLayout>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_map_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Activity class is inheriting `AppCompatActivity`.

BaseActivity.cs:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    //...
}
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
[Activity(Label = "MyApp", MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, Icon = "@drawable/Icon")]
public class MainActivity : BaseActivity
{
    //...
}
```

My Fragment is inheriting `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment`.

```
public abstract class BaseFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    //...
}
```

And finally here is my map fragment where the exception is being thrown when trying to inflate:

```
public class LocationFragment : BaseFragment, IOnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.IOnMapLongClickListener
{
    //...
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // exception thrown on following line
        return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.map, container, false);
    }
}
```

I'm guessing this may have something to do with having a fragment within a fragment.

Edit 1:

Just to clarify that I do indeed have the correct information in my manifest, here is a snippet of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.myPackage" android:versionCode="11" android:versionName="2.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
  <application android:label="MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="itsasecret" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="itsasecret" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

I also took steps to verify that my API key is valid.

[image]

My key matches what is in my manifest. The package name matches up as well. I also verified the SHA1 by running `keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\Jared\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`.

Comment: Have you added <meta-data> in Manifest??

Comment: I have and as far as I know, that wouldn't cause an exception to be thrown anyways. That would just cause the map to be blank. Or maybe that's just if you have the wrong API key. Either way, I do have it added.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out... sort of. I am now getting the map fragment properly when I first go to it, but I get the same inflate exception if I go to a different fragment and come back.

The "solution" to get this far was to remove `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="itsasecret" />` from my manifest. Applying the `API_KEY` to two different values apparently causes problems. Although the error I was getting was not indicating this whatsoever.

So now I have only one line for the `API_KEY`:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="itsasecret" />
```

I'll update my answer when I figure out why I'm getting the exception when coming back to the fragment a second time.

Edit: To fix the problem I was having, I ended up removing the fragment from the xml file entirely and adding it programmatically. No idea what was causing it in the first place, but this works.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_map_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout...>
            <CheckBox... />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout...>
          <CheckBox... />
        </LinearLayout>
        <EditText.../>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_below="@+id/top_map_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

LocationFragment.cs:

```
private MapFragment mapView;

public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //...
    mapView = MapFragment.NewInstance();

    var ft = Activity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    ft.Add(Resource.Id.map_placeholder, mapView).Commit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put your fragment inside  LinearLayout.../LinearLayout and deploy your application

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this? Any explanation on why this will solve my issue? Which `LinearLayout`? I feel like you're just taking a shot in the dark.

Comment: why don t you try it ! ? is there a problem ?  that s my suggestion to you so try it or leave it i, it s up to you

Comment: You still did not specify which `LinearLayout` you were referring to. I tried placing it in each `LinearLayout` and it still did not work. Perhaps you should be more specific or at least post some code or something.

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</LinearLayout> you do just like this

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to be helpful. Please note that I have had a `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment` within a `RelativeLayout` before in a previous project. It worked just fine.